# Not able to get bean when loading application context from jar

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am loading my application context from a jar file. The jar file contains all class files of war that is been created from maven by using `attachclasses=true`. The war file uses `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and `<context:component-scan />`. The components inside are annotated by `@Component`,`@Service` and `@Autowired` is also used. When I am doing

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:web-controller-application.xml");
applicationContext.getBean(AccountServiceImpl.class);
```

It says no qualified bean of this type is found where as the same works fine as spring mvc web-application.

Comment: I doubt the same works, I suspect you are using `AccountService` for auto wiring and not `AccountServiceImpl`. And I really hope that you aren't using the same construct to obtain beans in your web application!!!

Comment: I have got AccountServiceImpl annotated with @Service and I am using   Autowired  annotation with AccountService .

Comment: As I already stated. Spring uses proxies to apply AOP as soon as that happens there is no more `AccountServiceImpl` only an `AccountService`.

Comment: When I debugged the same,I get the feeling that no beans are created ,as  applicationContext.getBeansOfType(AccountService.class) as empty .Also,I get the same result if I use AccountServiceImpl in place of AccountService.

Comment: Well then enable debug logging to see what is happening. Also where is your `web-controller-application.xm` located?

Comment: it is inside the jar.The complete scenario is like I had spring web mvc project ,I have to create jar from it so as to access some common code as stand alone application.There is no error when I am loading applicationcontext but I some how I dont get any beans that have been created.

Comment: Is it in the root of the jar? Also if the file wouldn't be found you would get an exception. Thus as stated enable debug logging to get insight what the `ApplicationContext` is doing.

Comment: I stated the same thing .Since I am not getting filenotfoundexception ,this implies that I am able to load application context successfully.I am not able to get why the beans are not getting created

Comment: No you haven't... When you enable debug logging you can exactly see what files and beans are loaded... If nothing is loaded the file isn't in the location you specified it to be

Comment: can you please give me some idea on what point i might be missing as I am not getting filenotfoundexception

Comment: I give up... Enable debug logging and see what is happening or not happening or add the output to your post.

Comment: I am able to get the location of config files as configLocations whle  debugging.

Comment: I'm not talking about debugging, I'm talking about enabling DEBUG logging for `org.springframework`. Which will flood your log with everything that happens inside the `ApplicationContext`....